# Problem in accessing custom header in SwaggerUI while migrating from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, migration, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a custom authorization filter created in my .NET Core App that I use to authorize requests. This header in my .NET Core 2.1 used to look like this:

```
public class AddUnionAuthorizationHeader : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation == null) return;

        if (operation.Parameters == null)
        {
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();
        }

        var authorizeAttributes = context.ApiDescription
                                            .ControllerAttributes()
                                            .Union(context.ApiDescription.ActionAttributes())
                                            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>();

        if (!authorizeAttributes.Any())
            return;

        var parameter = new NonBodyParameter
        {
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = "header",
            Description = "The authorization token for a logged-in member.",
            Required = true,
            Type = "string"
        };
        operation.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
}
```

And I could access the token like this:

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{

   string authorizationBlob = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
   var authorizedMember = await authorizer.Check(authorizationBlob);

   //So on
}
```

Now I ported my app to .NET Core 3.1, so I used the following:

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
{
    if (operation == null) return;

    if (operation.Parameters == null)
    {
        operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();
    }

    var authorizeAttributes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>();


    if (!authorizeAttributes.Any())
        return;

    var parameter = new OpenApiParameter
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "The authorization token for a logged-in member.",
        Required = true,
        Schema = new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" }
    };

    operation.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

Now when I try to get the value of the token like this:

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{   
    StringValues authorizationToken;
    //string authorizationBlob = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
    string authorizationBlob = authorizationToken;
    var authorizedMember = await authorizer.Check(authorizationBlob);
}
```

The header is always coming empty.

The interesting part is when I change the `OpenApiParameter` definition to this:

```
var parameter = new OpenApiParameter
{
    Name = "X-Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Description = "The authorization token for a logged-in member.",
    Required = true,
    Schema = new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" }
};
```

Then I am able to access the token like this:

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Authorization", out authorizationToken);
string authorizationBlob = authorizationToken;
```

So my question is that why I am not able to retrieve the token when I use the `Name = "Authorization"` when I create my `OpenApiParameter` ?

The problem is that if I change the name to `Name = "X-Authorization"`, then I need to change it in the client app for all cases which will be cumbersome.

Any workaround on the above case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this 2 packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi" Version="1.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
```

I reproduced your issue, and I also think this is weird why `Authorization` won't work but `X-Authorization` or `Authorizations` can work, until I check the details of the `OpenApiParameter`...

> If in is "header" and the name field is "Accept", "Content-Type" or
> "Authorization", the parameter definition SHALL be ignored.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Per my understanding, OpenApiParameter in Swagger is used for test, it doesn't influnce the client code, when you send request from the client with a request header Authoration, your action filter will receive the value. So if you are doing this only for testing api, you can set a logic in action filter to check if the app is running in developing mode, if so then `TryGetValue("X-Authorization`, if not `TryGetValue("Authorization`